Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal
Issue
I can not access wp-admin page.
Example
https://example.net
→ I can access it .
https://example.net/wp-admin
→ I cannot access it . and output error
Error from server log
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer:
Now .htaccess
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*" AllowForeignWpLogin

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /home/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
SiteGuard_User_ExcludeSig 90101020
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*" AllowForeignXmlrpc
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*" AllowForeignWlwmanifest
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*" AllowForeignRestApi
SiteGuard_User_ExcludeSig 90101029
SiteGuard_User_ExcludeSig 00110011
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*" UnlimitedWpLogin
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*" UnlimitedWpComment



You have RewriteBase /home/ in there, and are redirecting to /home/index.php - sure that you should not be accessing https://example.net/home/wp-admin to begin with then? Give us some more details about your setup here.
